# sencha touch - hide titlebar of an Ext.navigation.View

Tags: sencha-touch

Is it possible to hide the titlebar of an Ext.navigation.View? I don't see any options in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
Ext.define('Nav', {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,

    navigationBar: {
        hidden: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! Was there some documentation on how to do this? Wasn't aware you could nest configuration like that...

Answer (score 3):

As an variation to jurodr's answer:

```
Ext.define("Nav", {   
  'Ext.navigation.View',
   config: {   
     fullscreen: true,
     navigationBar:false   
     }   
});
```

Comment: Noin, I have edited your answer: don't put al these &nbsp; in there, just indent 4 spaces